# XSLT 2.0 Replace Element Value if Contains String, Is Empty, or Doesn't Exist

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am attempting to perform a transformation on an XML document that looks like this:

```
<AutoInsurance>
    <Vehicles>
        <Vehicle>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Make>HONDA</Make>
            <Model>ACCORD</Model>
            <SubModel>EX</SubModel>
        </Vehicle>
    </Vehicles>
</AutoInsurance>
```

If the SubModel element contains useful data, I want to maintain it. However, if the element either contains '-', ''. or doesn't exist, I want to replace the value with 'NA'.

For example:

```
<AutoInsurance>
    <Vehicles>
        <Vehicle>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Make>HONDA</Make>
            <Model>ACCORD</Model>
            <SubModel>_</SubModel>
        </Vehicle>
    </Vehicles>
</AutoInsurance>
```

```
<AutoInsurance>
    <Vehicles>
        <Vehicle>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Make>HONDA</Make>
            <Model>ACCORD</Model>
            <SubModel></SubModel>
        </Vehicle>
    </Vehicles>
</AutoInsurance>
```

```
<AutoInsurance>
    <Vehicles>
        <Vehicle>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Make>HONDA</Make>
            <Model>ACCORD</Model>
        </Vehicle>
    </Vehicles>
</AutoInsurance>
```

Should all transform to

```
<AutoInsurance>
    <Vehicles>
        <Vehicle>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Make>HONDA</Make>
            <Model>ACCORD</Model>
            <SubModel>NA</SubModel>
        </Vehicle>
    </Vehicles>
</AutoInsurance>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which chars are these: either contains '-', ''.? A dot, underscore and dash?

Comment: Does *contains '-'* mean *contains ONLY '-'*? Or does it include say  `<SubModel>abc-def</SubModel>`?

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a variable with the strings that should lead to 'NA'.

And use it like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  >
  
  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:variable name="wrongStrings" as="xs:string*" select="'-','_','.'" />
  
  <xsl:template match="Vehicle">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::SubModel)]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="subModelContent" as="xs:string" select="if(SubModel/text()) then SubModel/text() else '-'"/>
    <SubModel>
      <xsl:value-of select="if($subModelContent=$wrongStrings) then 'NA' else SubModel/text()"/>
    </SubModel>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When you have this xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <AutoInsurance>
    <Vehicles>
      <Vehicle>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Make>HONDA</Make>
        <Model>ACCORD</Model>
        <SubModel>_</SubModel>
      </Vehicle>
    </Vehicles>
  </AutoInsurance>
  <AutoInsurance>
    <Vehicles>
      <Vehicle>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Make>HONDA</Make>
        <Model>ACCORD</Model>
        <SubModel></SubModel>
      </Vehicle>
    </Vehicles>
  </AutoInsurance>
  <AutoInsurance>
    <Vehicles>
      <Vehicle>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Make>HONDA</Make>
        <Model>ACCORD</Model>
      </Vehicle>
    </Vehicles>
  </AutoInsurance>
  <AutoInsurance>
    <Vehicles>
      <Vehicle>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Make>HONDA</Make>
        <Model>ACCORD</Model>
        <SubModel>ABC</SubModel>
      </Vehicle>
    </Vehicles>
  </AutoInsurance>
</root>
```

The result would be this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <AutoInsurance>
    <Vehicles>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Make>HONDA</Make>
      <Model>ACCORD</Model>
      <SubModel>NA</SubModel>
    </Vehicles>
  </AutoInsurance>
  <AutoInsurance>
    <Vehicles>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Make>HONDA</Make>
      <Model>ACCORD</Model>
      <SubModel>NA</SubModel>
    </Vehicles>
  </AutoInsurance>
  <AutoInsurance>
    <Vehicles>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Make>HONDA</Make>
      <Model>ACCORD</Model>
      <SubModel>NA</SubModel>
    </Vehicles>
  </AutoInsurance>
  <AutoInsurance>
    <Vehicles>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Make>HONDA</Make>
      <Model>ACCORD</Model>
      <SubModel>ABC</SubModel>
    </Vehicles>
  </AutoInsurance>
</root>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Vehicle">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(name()='SubModel')]"/>
    <SubModel><xsl:value-of select="if(string-length(SubModel) lt 2) then 'NA' else SubModel"/></SubModel>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here I just placed 'NA' in SubModel if the input text is less than 2 characters but you could use another criteria to better suit your requirements.